# Alt + E, S suddenly not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

Yesterday 'Paste Special' using the right mouse click and the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> stopped working.

`Application.commandbars("cell").reset` did reset the right click option, but using the keyboard is still not possible.

I'm using Excel 2007, on Windows 7. (I know this is an Excel 2003 shortcut, but it has always worked in 2007, until now.)

I've looked all over online and can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Just tested this on Excel 2010 and worked fine for me. Has anything changed in the system.

Comment: How about other, old key combinations, like Alt+V? Also note the ability to disable certain shortcut keys, although I find would assume it's unlikely that something like this happened by accident: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179143(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I feel a little dumb...

I have code in one of my workbooks that disables all copy/paste functions at open, then re-enables at close. Somehow the paste-special was not re-enabled, even though normal copy/paste was. It finally dawned on me to look at that after reading this post at MrExcel.com: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/332832-alt-keys-2007-a.html

Thank you all for your suggestions :)

Comment: Please remember to mark your answer as the correct solution once you get the chance to do it. Good job on researching the problem yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with Alt_A, in Word.

Pressing the Alt and letter keys *sequentially* worked but not when they were pressed *simultaneously*.

Cause= I had assigned a macro to Alt_A!!!

Answer (score -1):

Found this from Microsoft Answers for Excel: It resolved my problem :)

Please look into C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel (replace user name with your user name, you can directly reach here by copy and pasting following without quotes in Explorer address bar - "%appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\") and see if is contains few files / folders. Move those files to some other location (i.e create a backup of those files / folders and delete all files / folders from here). Hence, make Excel folder blank.

Now open the file and see if the problem disappears or not.

Note - to find Excel path, you need to find XLSTART path. Excel folder contains XLSTART folder in itself (In case, your XLSTART path is not in Appdata)

1. Open Excel
2. ALT+F11
3. If Immediate Window is not visible, type CTRL+G. Same can be also be accessed through View > Immediate Window
4. Type "? application.StartupPath" without quotes and press enter
5. You will have your path below.
6. You may login to Windows with a new user profile and see if it helps.
7. Turn off Hey Cortana and reboot your computer (useful particularly if Excel performance is slow).

Link to Answer : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-excel/enabling-excel-shortcut-keys/02b4c8fc-c4f7-46aa-a616-e40f262a0d38?auth=1

Answer (score -3):

Yesterday 'Paste Special' using the right mouse click and the keyboard shortcut Alt +E,S stopped working.

Answer-Try Alt+H+V+V

Comment: Why is your answer supposed to work? Please explain. Also, read [answer] and add some content to your answer.